# running mysqld in a docker container. mysql client requires sudo. Mysql workbench cannot connect, how to fix?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am running mariadb in a docker container, and can reach it from the command line with:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p mydb
```

It asks for my password for the sudo, then the root password of the database, and it then works.

But I want to run mysql workbench. When I do, it will run (does not require sudo) but won't connect. I tried running with sudo, but then it can't open windows.

I would like to run without sudo anyway.
mysql workbench just says can't connect. How do I see what is wrong, and if it's obvious, how do I fix this?

Comment: I guess you run `mysql workbench` outside of the mysql docker? How your connection url looks like?

Comment: @Jens, I am running mysql out of the mysql docker (and it works) and mysql workbench is the same. mysql is presumably trying to reach localhost:3306, and that's what workbench shows by default as well.

Comment: Use the docker name instead of localhost.

Comment: @Jens that sounded brilliant and sensible but it says host not found?
The name is mysql1. It's not the container id, is it?

Comment: Run docker ps and you should see the name. You can also add the output here

Comment: WHen I killed the docker, it turned out it was not even being used. mysql was running against the same mariadb, but running as a service on my machine. But that was very useful information for next time, so thanks!